# NGINX Two Directories One URL (Codeigniter, HTML)

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

Here is my default.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html/;
    server_name example.com;

    # Site 01
    location /* {
        alias /var/www/html/home/;
        index index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /home/index.html;
    }

    # Site 2
    location /shadows {
        alias /var/www/html/shadows/;
        index index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /shadows/index.php;
    }

    error_page 404 /error/404.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I have a Codeigniter app in

```
var/www/html/shadows
```

I also have a HTML site in

```
var/www/html/home
```

The issue:

I have been able to make this work for the directories home or shadows but not both.

If I change root to /var/www/html/home the HTML site pops up.

Currently just the shadows codeigniter site pops up with this configuration.

Please let me know your thoughts on resolving this. Thank you very much.

Comment: *"Two Directories One URL"* – it's not clear to me what you actually want to achieve… you can't have one URL point to two locations…?

Comment: Yes I want www.url.com to point to the html site located in var/www/html/home and I want url.com/shadows to point to var/www/html/shadows    in there the shadows part is my codeigniter app.

Comment: Your PHP handler `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` uses your default root `/var/www/html/` thus not being able to find your Codeigniter PHP files. Additionally, change `location /* { ... }` to `location / { ... }`. Does your HTML site at `/var/www/html/home` makes use of PHP files too?

Comment: Some of them, yes. I have a headless CMS there.

Comment: How can I change location  ~ \.php$ { ... } to not use my default  root /var/www/html/ as you described?

Comment: @d7l2k4 Answered. When you write a comment under some discussion where more than two people involved, to ensure your comment will be delivered to the right person index, start your comment with a user name, e.g. `@IvanShatsky`. I could easily miss your reply.

Comment: Sorry about that, and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `root` directive value via the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block:

```
map $uri $approot {
    ~^/shadows/    /var/www/html;
    default        /var/www/html/home;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root $approot;
    server_name example.com;

    # Site 01
    location / {
        index index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Site 2
    location /shadows/ {
        index index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /shadows/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /error/404.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming your HTML site should be served under the root prefix `/`, not the `/home/`, therefore I changed your `try_files $uri $uri/ /home/index.html;` directive to the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`. I also replaced all your `alias` directives with `root` ones. As it said by the `alias` directive [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

> When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     alias /data/w3/images/;
> }
> ```
>
> it is better to use the `root` directive instead:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```

Additionally there is a well-known [bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) when you are using `alias` and `try_files` directives together, so using the `root` one instead is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should work:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/html/home;

    location /shadows {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
    }
}
```

http://example.com/shadows/index.php will resolve to path `/var/www/html/shadows/index.php` in this case.

Comment: I followed the instructions above exactly. However, I am getting a NGINX 404 not found at http://myip/shadows but http://myip works

Comment: In case of accessing via IP you have to ensure that this is your `default_server`… I just made an edit that could help.

Comment: Still 404 no found error. Please note that my home page is in var/www/html/home and my shadows backend is in var/www/html/shadows does this change the configuration at all? I did systemctl restart nginx